# change the url send to emails

Tags: uri

I am quite new in developing in Drupal.

My problem is this, I want to change the URL sent in the email when the someone registers to my website. My website is in 192.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite.

How can i change the verification link from `192.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite/user/reset/some-hash-code` to `www.mywebsite.com/user/reset/some-hash-code`.

I tried changing the `$base_url` in the `settings.php` but it crashes my site.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can change it to `www.mywebsite.com` by visiting the site via `www.mywebsite.com` and clear cache.

Comment: @NikhilM I did it already, I went to `www.mywebsite.com` then register through the normal registration process but still the email sent to me for the validation link is the IP. `192.xx.xx.xx/mywebsite/user/reset/some-hash-code`

Comment: Check your settings.php for `$base_url`

Comment: @NikhilM what should i put in there? if i put `www.aklabox.com` it crashes my site.

Comment: It says `Base URL (optional).` you leave it empty and clear cache. And you dont need to place full URL in the email template use the tokens.

Comment: @NikhilM yup, I've tried that. I've commented the `$base_url` and cleared my cache also using `drush`.. also in email template I use tokens, it is by default, `[user:one-time-login-url]` but still the email I get when i register is still the `IP/myswebsite`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14619/discussion-between-nikhil-m-and-karl-michael-linantud).